# Rechunk a conduit into larger chunks using combinators

Tags: haskell, chunking, conduit

I am trying to construct a `Conduit` that receives as input `ByteString`s (of around 1kb per chunk in size) and produces as output concatenated `ByteString`s of 512kb chunks.

This seems like it should be simple to do, but I'm having a lot of trouble, most of the strategies I've tried using have only succeeded in dividing the chunks into smaller chunks, I haven't succeeded in concatenating larger chunks.

I started out trying `isolate`, then `takeExactlyE` and eventually `conduitVector`, but to no avail. Eventually I settled on this:

```
import qualified Data.Conduit               as C
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators   as C
import qualified Data.ByteString            as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL

chunksOfAtLeast :: Monad m => Int -> C.Conduit B.ByteString m BL.ByteString
chunksOfAtLeast chunkSize = loop BL.empty chunkSize
  where 
    loop buffer n = do
      mchunk <- C.await
      case mchunk of 
        Nothing -> 
          -- Yield last remaining bytes
          when (n < chunkSize) (C.yield buffer)
        Just chunk -> do
          -- Yield when the buffer has been filled and start over
          let buffer' = buffer <> BL.fromStrict chunk
              l       = B.length chunk
          if n <= l
          then C.yield buffer' >> loop BL.empty chunkSize
          else loop buffer' (n - l)
```

*<sub>P.S. I decided not to split larger chunks for this function, but this was just a convenient simplification.</sub>*

However, this seems very verbose given all the conduit functions that deal with chunking<sup>[[1](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/vectorbuilder),[2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators-0.2.8.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Combinators.html),[3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.3.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Binary.html),[4](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.3.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Blaze.html)]</sup>. Please help! There must surely be a better way to do this using combinators, but I am missing some piece of intuition!

*<sub>P.P.S. Is it ok to use lazy bytestring for the buffer as I've done? I'm a bit unclear about the internal representation for bytestring and whether this will help, especially since I'm using `BL.length` which I guess might evaluate the thunk anyway?</sub>*

---

### Conclusion

Just to elaborate on Michael's answer and comments, I ended up with this conduit:

```
import qualified Data.Conduit               as C
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators   as C
import qualified Data.ByteString            as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL

-- | "Strict" rechunk of a chunked conduit
chunksOfE' :: (MonadBase base m, PrimMonad base) 
         => Int 
         -> C.Conduit ByteString m ByteString
chunksOfE' chunkSize = C.vectorBuilder chunkSize C.mapM_E =$= C.map fromByteVector
```

My understanding is that `vectorBuilder` will pay the cost for concatenating the smaller chunks early on, producing the aggregated chunks as strict bytestrings.

From what I can tell, an alternative implementation that produces lazy bytestring chunks (i.e. *"chunked chunks"*) might be desirable when the aggregated chunks are very large and/or feed into a naturally streaming interface like a network socket. Here's my best attempt at the "lazy bytestring" version:

```
import qualified Data.Sequences.Lazy        as SL
import qualified Data.Sequences             as S
import qualified Data.Conduit.List          as CL

-- | "Lazy" rechunk of a chunked conduit
chunksOfE :: (Monad m, SL.LazySequence lazy strict)
          => S.Index lazy
          -> C.Conduit strict m lazy
chunksOfE chunkSize = CL.sequence C.sinkLazy =$= C.takeE chunkSize
```

Comment: Also, incredibly, I haven't managed to find an example that does only this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import ClassyPrelude.Conduit

chunksOfAtLeast :: Monad m => Int -> Conduit ByteString m LByteString
chunksOfAtLeast chunkSize =
    loop
  where
    loop = do
        lbs <- takeCE chunkSize =$= sinkLazy
        unless (null lbs) $ do
            yield lbs
            loop

main :: IO ()
main =
    yieldMany ["hello", "there", "world!"]
        $$ chunksOfAtLeast 3
        =$ mapM_C print
```

There are lots of other approaches that you could take depending on your goals. If you wanted to have a strict buffer, then using blaze-builder of vectorBuilder would make a lot of sense. But this keeps the same type signature you have already.

Comment: Thanks!! I think the multiple approaches is one of the things that has really confused me. I expected something like `C.takeExactlyE chunkSize C.concat` to work, I'm still not sure I understand why it doesn't...?

Comment: Oh, or rather, I felt like I should be able to write something very similar to `forever $ C.takeExactlyE chunkSize C.concat` except that `forever` doesn't terminate...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some trouble compiling your example `Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘BL.ByteString’` (not using ClassyPrelude). Also, does the chunks of work with `chunksOfAtLeast 8`? It's trying get larger chunks rather than smaller chunks for a file upload over https...

Comment: I think you answered your `forever` point yourself: `forever` never terminates. Regarding `takeExactlyE` vs `takeE`: the only difference is when the downstream doesn't fully consume the input, but `sinkLazy` *does* always consume all its input, so the two can be used interchangeably here. Instead of `concat`, `fold` is the combinator you're looking for, which would simply change the output type from `LByteString` to `ByteString`.

Comment: Do you think it would make sense for me to abstract in terms of something like a `takeForever` function with behaviour similar to `awaitForever`?

Comment: What I mean is that I'd like to try and get to a combinator style solution if it's possible, eliding the loop... EDIT: Oh or are you saying I should try and use `fold`.... Thanks let me try this first.

Comment: Regarding `fold`: there are three different ways I can think of to aggregate the `ByteString`s: into a lazy `ByteString`, folding them together, or converting to a `Builder` and concatenating the `Builder`. All of them are valid, it depends on what you want to do with the output. It's certainly possible to put together some kind of combinator like `takeForever`. There's also the possibility you mentioned of using [conduitVector](http://lpaste.net/109758).

Comment: That `conduitVector` solution in you paste seems perfect to me, I'll give that a try. I have a little bit of trouble understanding the performance implications of the various solutions but this is probably due to inexperience on my part with things like `Buillder`. It's always awesome when a library author answers your SO question, thanks!

Comment: One more version on vectorBuilder which is likely a bit faster: http://lpaste.net/8310511707713699840