# Efficient chunking of conduit for strict bytestring

Tags: haskell, conduit

This is a followup to this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428065/rechunk-a-conduit-into-larger-chunks-using-combinators). I have a conduit source (from `Network.HTTP.Conduit`) which is strict `ByteString`. I will like to recombine them into larger chunks (to send over network to another client, after another encoding and conversion to lazy bytestring). I wrote `chunksOfAtLeast` conduit, derived from the answer in above question which seems to work pretty well. I am wondering if there is any further scope for improving it performance-wise.

```
import Data.Conduit as C
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad
import Data.Conduit.Combinators as CC
import Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS hiding (putStrLn)
import Data.ByteString as BS hiding (putStrLn)

chunksOfAtLeast :: Monad m => Int -> Conduit BS.ByteString m BS.ByteString
chunksOfAtLeast chunkSize =
    loop
  where
    loop = do
        bs <- takeE chunkSize =$= ((BS.concat . ($ [])) <$> CL.fold (\front next -> front . (next:)) id)
        unless (BS.null bs) $ do
            yield bs
            loop

main = do
  yieldMany ["hello", "there", "world!"] $$ chunksOfAtLeast 8 =$ CL.mapM_ Prelude.print
```

Comment: What does the profiler say?

Comment: I tested this one through `RTS -s` instead of criterion microbenchmarking. I get about 30MB/s throughput per core (on an AWS medium m3 instance). Seems pretty decent to me. Just curious if there are any other performance tricks I could use as well. Or if this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting optimal performance is always a case of trying something and benchmarking it, so I can't tell you with certainty that I'm offering you something more efficient. That said, combining smaller chunks of data into larger chunks is a primary goal of [builders](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.4/bytestring-0.10.6.0/Data-ByteString-Builder.html), so leveraging them may be more efficient. Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Conduit
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.ByteString.Builder (byteString)
import Data.Conduit.ByteString.Builder

bufferChunks :: Conduit ByteString IO ByteString
bufferChunks = mapC byteString =$= builderToByteString

main :: IO ()
main = yieldMany ["hello", "there", "world!"] $$ bufferChunks =$ mapM_C print
```